# Bind multiple input files into IEnumerable

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, model-binding

I am using ASP.NET MVC for a small website. I can't find a way to bind multiple file inputs into one `IEnumerable`.

I have the following inputs in my view:

```
<input type="file" name="medical-certificate-file" id="medical-certificate-file">
<input type="file" name="manager-degree-doc-file" id="manager-degree-doc-file">
```

My model is looking like this:

```
public class Document
{
      public DocumentType DocumentType { get; set; }
      public IFormFile File { get; set; }
}

public class InputModel
{
      public IEnumerable<Document> Documents { get; set; }
}
```

I tried mapping the file the way I successfully map other form data - changing the name property:

```
<input type="file" name="Documents.File" id="medical-certificate-file">
```

This solution works, but of course only for one file. The second, logically, cannot be mapped with the same name.

I also tried to use asp-for, like this:

```
<input asp-for="Documents.ElementAt(0).File" type="file" name="medical-certificate-file" id="medical-certificate-file">
```

This solution doesn't even work for a single file. I also tried different varieties of it.

I should note that it is important that the input forms are multiple and not one with multiple files selection option. There are several files, not just two as I indicate in the example.

Thanks in advance for your time!

Comment: Where is the `File` property coming from? The `IFile` interface doesn't have it and `IEnumerable` doesn't either. Have you tried `asp-for="Documents"`?

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry! I wanted to give only what was relevant to my problem, but I think I shortened the example too much and it was not accurate. I have just edited my question.

Comment: Try `asp-for="Documents.Select(x => x.File)"`

Comment: Unfortunately, does not work. I wonder if mapping each file input to a separate IFormFile is the best option.

Answer (score 0):

The complex object binding makes use of a sequential index. The index must start at 0, and it must be sequential, as its name suggests. There must be no gaps. The index is placed in square brackets and added to the form field's name attribute e.g `name="Documents[0].file"`

Try to use `name="Documents[0].file"` to bind file to the IEnumerable Documents :

```
<input type="file" name="Documents[0].file" id="medical-certificate-file">
<input type="file" name="Documents[1].file" id="manager-degree-doc-file">
```

the demo like:

```
<form asp-action="Index"  enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <input type="file" name="Documents[0].file" id="medical-certificate-file">
    <input type="file" name="Documents[1].file" id="manager-degree-doc-file">

    <input type="submit" value="Create" />
</form>
```

result:

[image]

**Or** :

```
@for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    <input type="file" name="Documents[@i].file" id="medical-certificate-file">
}
```

result:
[image]

Comment: Hi @Mladen Nikolov , any update? If my answer help you resolve your issue?
 If not, could you please follow up to let me know?